# Iterating over Linked List using Functional programming paradigm

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

I have a simple Linked list in my project. The project uses underscore.js. I am trying to think of a way to iterate over the linked list using functional programming techniques. Currently, I have the following:

```
while(cell.next) {
  nxt = cell.next;
  //check if next cell fulfills some condition. If condition is met,
  // loop breaks
}
```

Is there any way to implement the above in a functional manner (using underscore.js library)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how underscore would factor in. Doesn't really seem necessary to get functional style code.

```
function doCell(c) {
    if (!c || your_condition_is_met)
        return c;
    return doCell(c.next);
}

var result = doCell(cell);
```

Not sure what the result is supposed to be, so I just returned the current cell if the condition is met.

---

You could abstract some of it away into a reusable function if you wish.

```
function nextWhile(v, callback) {
    if (!v || callback(v))
        return v;
    return nextWhile(v.next, callback);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var result = nextWhile(cell, function(cell) {
    return your_condition_is_met;
});
```

---

And this lets you create reusable functions.

```
function cell_is_something(cell) {
    return your_condition_is_met;
}
```

Which cleans up and documents your code.

```
var result = nextWhile(cell, cell_is_something);
```